# How to especific path external-path for apps with dynamic applicationId

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm using FileProvider in my app, when I take a picture from the app is stored there. also my app have a different application id for debug and release builds

- com.rkmax.myapp
- com.rkmax.myapp.debug

I have defined my file provider like this

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="@string/authority_file_provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

the value of `@string/authority_file_provider` will turn into:

- com.rkmax.myapp.fileprovider
- com.rkmax.myapp.debug.fileprovider

and my `@xml/file_paths` is defined like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.rkmax.myapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

if I try to changes to something like `Pictures` or `files/Pictures` my app fails

```
Failed to find configured root that contains/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rkmax.myapp.debug/files/Pictures/20161112_073128-251269360.jpg
```

How I define a relative path in the file provider paths?

Answer (score 14):

For your particular case, replace:

```
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.rkmax.myapp/files/Pictures" />
```

with:

```
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
```

This will require 24.0.0 or higher of the support libraries, IIRC.

Comment: Same error. After tos of trial error I get this working, replacing the path by `.`

Comment: @rkmax: For the particular file in your question, that should not be necessary AFAIK. There could be other files that you are serving, not in `Pictures/`, for which you would need `.` as the path, though.